How to add AutomationID to WPF Combobox items
How I can add AutomationID to WPF Combobox items for test automation?
Now when I examine application with Inspect.exe, FlaUInspect or Windows narrator all I can see is a text of a list item.
I found that this problem has been around a years but is there any solution to help test automation to use wpf combobox items.
Inspect.exe
I found one hint and tried adding this code to a combobox without help.
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" 
                            Value="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>


This question is similar to: XAML - Automation ID for ComboBox elements in DataGridComboBoxColumn. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am not using ComboBox inside DataGridComboBoxColumn so I assume I should have not so complex and easier case.
